# Why org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils.parse("param1=%C3%A9", Charset.forName("UTF-8")) returns "é"?

Tags: utf-8, character-encoding

I try to understand why URLEncodedUtils.parse(String, Charset) method is changing my parameter encoding.

Here is my assert, which I think should be wrong, but which returns true:

```
assertEquals(URLEncodedUtils.parse("param1=%C3%A9", Charset.forName("UTF-8")).get(0).getValue(), "é");
```

As %C3%A9 is already the UTF-8 encoded value for "é", I don't expect it to be converted.

Here what I expect to be true:

```
assertEquals(URLEncodedUtils.parse("param1=%C3%A9", Charset.forName("UTF-8")).get(0).getValue(), "%C3%A9");
```

Comment: Why would you expect that? It's parsing the URL, decoding percent-escaped bytes sequences into characters. As you say, %C3%A9 is encoded, and the parse operation is meant to *decode* that...

Comment: The POST content I'm extracting has been hashed, and I need to retrieve each parameter value as it was if I want to get a chance to verify the hash.
But as I get "é", rather than the original %C3%A9, my checking fails.

Comment: If you want the raw unparsed data, you shouldn't be calling `parse`. The method is doing exactly what it's meant to - it's just not what you want to do.

Comment: You're correct. I added your answer.

Comment: you can use `StandardCharsets.UTF_8`

Answer (score 0):

URLEncodedUtils.parse(String, Charset) worked as expected.

In fact, the http client should have hashed "é", then sent %C3%A9 in the content. I would then have decoded %C3%A9 in "é", and could have hashed it.